# Precargar imagenes en página web

Tags: javascript, html, css

me gusta mucho el desarrollo de páginas web y en estos últimos días me he interesado bastante en las páginas de Apple por sus diseños.

Me interesé bastante en el estilo de la página de la nueva MacBook Pro de 16 pulgadas, en el cual podemos observar como la macbook va abriendo mientras hacemos scroll en la página.

No se como los desarrolladores de Apple lo hacen, pero con lo poco que se logré hacer algo parecido, básicamente corrí un javascript una variable que capture la cantidad de scroll que hago en la página, luego lo divido entre 10 y me da un valor, el cual coinciden con el nombre de la imagen y hago que se presenten una por una.

El problema es que cuando hago scroll en la prueba, no se queda estática; las imagenes aparecen y desaparacen, claro; luego de hacerlo varias veces pues ya si se puede observar fluido.

Me gustaría si existe una forma de mejorar esto, ya sea precargando las imagenes o de alguna forma cualquiera, para que desde que haga el primer intento se pueda observar el efecto fluido.

Comment: Quizá esto es lo que buscas: [Como quitar parpadeo al cargar imágenes en slideshow?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/156042/como-quitar-parpadeo-al-cargar-im%c3%a1genes-en-slideshow/156373#156373)

Comment: Muchas gracias, es exactamente lo que necesitaba.